# Programming selectable Pebble Watchfaces (Time)

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I have started with Pebble watchfaces programming on my Pebble Time, and although the watchface displays fine, it is loaded as an **application**, not a watchface, in that it is available in the list of applications, not the watchfaces sub-menu. I found that there are watchface online development sites that will produce actual watchfaces that get installed as such.

What is the difference ? What would I have to add to the code to make it a watchface ? Or manifest file ? The samples with the SDK were all for applications, not watchfaces.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch apps can do more things than watch faces can. For example, watch faces can't respond to button clicks. The SDK (CloudPebble or the C SDK) generates different code for the two types of programs. So you have to tell it what you are trying to build.
In the appinfo.json file there is a section like

```
"watchapp": {
"watchface": false
```

},

Change **false** to **true** and it should start showing up as a watch face

Comment: I guess this is a change that I have to manually perform on the archive file, and re-compress the file. Is there any easy way to change it in the Pebble SDK ?

Comment: Yes, the source to your program has an appinfo.json. You can't just edit the uncompressed PBW, because the SDK also changes the binary files to reflect the appinfo.json. If you're on CloudPebble you can change it under the settings of the project.